# c# create 7z archive, then Can not open file "name.7z" as an archive

Tags: c#, archive, 7zip

I am trying to zip some folders. They have different paths, will not belong to the same directory.

I tested the command line arguments that I would give, and it works, but I can't get it to work from c#:

```
string destination = "some path\\name.7z";
string pathToZip = "path to zip\\7z.exe";  // or 7za.exe
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.FileName = pathToZip;
p.Arguments = "a \"" + destination + "\" \"";
// room for the foreach - but even one directory doesn't work right now
   p.Arguments += directoryPath + "\" \"";
p.Arguments += "\" -mx=9 -aoa";
Process x = Process.Start(p);
```

With 7z.exe i get a blink; With 7za.exe, I get the typical command-line zip sequence, with files zipping through, adding to archive, and an archive gets created.

Then I go to it and right-click, open or double-click... and I get that it is an invalid archive (`Can not open file "name.7z" as an archive`). Try command line, with 7za, to extract - same thing.

Edit: I found the solution:

My problem was the **-aoa** option (which I used for overwrite) - after removing it, it worked.

Comment: Whatever you're doing with p.Arguments sucks somehow and no human can read that without getting internal eye bleeds!

Comment: Agreed. I recommend `StringBuilder` here, since you're doing string concatenation inside a for/foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me, packs a directory with files within:

```
string destination = @"c:\my test.7z";
string pathToZip = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe";
string directoryPath = @"c:\my test";

ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.FileName = pathToZip;
p.Arguments = string.Format("a -mx=9 \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", destination, directoryPath);

Process x = Process.Start(p);
```

Comment: Just don't forget to add `"` to take care of spaces in paths.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot :). I believe author's problem was the order of arguments: first option, then switches, than archive name and directory/files pathes.

Comment: My problem was the -aoa option (which I used for overwrite) ! after using your exact syntax and seeing how it still didn't work, I removed it and it did.

Answer (score 0):

`7za.exe` is the command line program, you should use it in this instance.

Why are you adding `""` to your command line? That may be causing your problem.

Also, make sure you put your `"` around things, don't pad with two of them at the end, that just causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

If the command line works, maybe just use a different start function; the one that takes the path to the exe, and the command line parameters in the second parameter.

[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx).

If the command line works, this may be the best way.